# I get error constant expression required

Tags: c, mplab

I'm using this inside a Header File:

```
typedef struct
{
 int DefaultValue;

}SetValues;

extern volatile SetValues XronosTrofodosias;
```

And this inside my Source file:

```
volatile SetValues XronosTrofodosias;

int  *DefaultValuesWaterSubMenu[]={XronosTrofodosias.DefaultValue};
```

Why i get this error? How can i fix that?

Here is my Real String

```
int  *DefaultValuesWaterSubMenu[]={XronosTrofodosias.DefaultValue,XronosAdranias.DefaultValue,XronosTrofodosiasHighTemp.DefaultValue,Xronos1hsRipsis.DefaultValue,Xronos2hsRipsis.DefaultValue,Kathisterisi2hsRipsis.DefaultValue,Energopoihsi2hsRipsis.DefaultValue,0,XronosAnemistiraOn.DefaultValue,XronosAnemistiraOff.DefaultValue,AnamoniAnemistira.DefaultValue,AdraniaAisthitiraFloagas.DefaultValue,StrofesAnafleksis.DefaultValue,AnoOrioAisthitiraFloagas.DefaultValue,KatoOrioAisthitiraFloagas.DefaultValue,EnergopohisiAisthitiriou.DefaultValue,OrioThermokrasiasKausaerion.DefaultValue,OrioThermokrasiasNerou.DefaultValue,KathisterisiAnemistira.DefaultValue,EnergopoihsiEksanemismou.DefaultValue,DiarkiaEksanemismou.DefaultValue,0,StrofesKausisAnemistira.DefaultValue,ThermokrasiaEkkinisisKikloforiti.DefaultValue,AnoOrioThermokrasiasNerou.DefaultValue,KatoOrioThermokrasiasNerou.DefaultValue,AnoOrioThermokrasiasKausaerion.DefaultValue,KatoOrioThermokrasiasKausaerion.DefaultValue};
```

Comment: you cannot initialize an array with a non-constant value.

Comment: Which is the other way?

Comment: Besides being non-constant, you also have incompativle types. `DefaultValue` is of type integer, whereas your array holds pointers to integer.

Comment: that and what size should have your array? because it's not defined at all. Should it be 1? in that case you don't need an array. Should it be able to resize?

Comment: I want just take the value. The value is only numbers

Comment: why an array? there's only 1 value in it

Comment: In my example there is only one array. In my real project they are about 28 values.I read each value from epprom and then i need to show them each one separately

Comment: See my edited example. Is there any way more easy?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize the array with values which are unknown at compile time which makes them non-constant.

Also the array contains elements of type int* and you are trying to initialize it with values of type int.

A fix to the first problem would be to initialize each element separately:

```
DefaultValuesWaterSubMenu[0] = ....;
```

A fix to the second porblem would be to change the array to contain int values

```
int DefaultValuesWaterSubMenu[10];

DefaultValuesWaterSubMenu[0] = XronosTrofodosias.DefaultValue;
```

Or

```
DefaultValuesWaterSubMenu[0] = &XronosTrofodosias.DefaultValue;
```

Comment: @Dim are you sure you did it right, becouse the error should be gone?

Comment: Any help for solving this?

Comment: I compiled it successfully so you must be doing something wrong

Comment: Can i use extern const int instead typedef??