# Use volatile type inside an array

Tags: c, mplab

I need to create some extern volatile variables. Then inside each variable to get a value from epprom. and then to combine this values inside an array

Header File:

```
typedef struct
{
    int Value;     
} SetValues;

extern volatile SetValues Mytest1;
extern volatile SetValues Mytest2;
extern volatile SetValues Mytest3;
```

Source File:

```
volatile SetValues Mytest1;
volatile SetValues Mytest2;
volatile SetValues Mytest3;


Mytest1.Value = DATAEE_ReadByte(21); // Here i'm reading from epprom
Mytest2.Value = DATAEE_ReadByte(22); // Here i'm reading from epprom

// i need each eeprom values(from volatile variables) to get them inside an array

int  *CheckMyValue[] = {Mytest1.Value, Mytest2.Value ... };
```

I get error  constant expression required. How can i change this to for make it work?

Comment: You do know in advance the number of values, rigth? Also, please post the compiler+version and your compiler switches.

Comment: Also, not  that `int *CheckMyValue` should be `int CheckMyValue`. The items are `int` not   `int *`.

Comment: Don't _initialize_ `CheckMyValue` during declaration but _assign_ it for example in the `main` function: `CheckMyValue[0] = Mytest1.Value; CheckMyValue[1] = Mytest2.Value; ...`

Comment: BTW why do you have a `struct` containing one single `int`? Why not use an just `int`?

Comment: My compiler version is xc8.Please write an example

Comment: please don't post the same question again on several accounts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619717/i-get-error-constant-expression-required asked this morning and has correct answers.

Comment: I dont get examples

Comment: that's not a good reason to repost (and create another account!!!). Edit the other question instead. now expect hell from users.

Comment: @dim My first comment contains an example.

Comment: Where should i create int myarray before main?Also i have 30 variables should make it for each one isnt there any shorter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize variables with values not known at compile time.

Instead of:

```
...
int *CheckMyValue[] = {Mytest1.Value, Mytest2.Value ... };
```

write:

```
...
#define NVALUES number_of_possible_values   // put the appropriate number here
...
int CheckMyValue[NVALUES];
...
int main()
{
  CheckMyValue[0] = Mytest1.Value;
  CheckMyValue[1] = Mytest2.Value;
  ...
```

Second problem:

`CheckMyValue` is an array of `int`, but you declare it as an array of pointers to `int`. So `int *CheckMyValue[];` should be changed to `int CheckMyValue[NVALUES];` where `NVALUES` is the number of entries in the array.

Comment: (499) undefined symbol:

Comment: Where do you get this error message? Which symbol?

Comment: There is no storage allocation for the array

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername yes, there is, press F5. The answer has been edited 6 minutes ago

Comment: @dim You need to substitute `number_of_possible_values` by whatever appropriate value, that is the maximum number of elements the `CheckMyValue` array can contain.

Comment: @MichaelWalz haven't you recognized the help vampire already?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, maybe, but I'm not sure _which_ one it is

Comment: Very unreadable answer in this form. You address invalid code posted by the OP by replacing it with a piece of another invalid code and after that explain that it's wrong as well.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername a typo, edited

Comment: Ok the code works thank you! But i have 30 variables... Can i make it with a loop instead to write it 28 times?

Comment: @dim yes you could do it e.g. with a loop, provided you don't have n times`volatile SetValues MytestX;` but a single `volatile SetValues Mytest[NUMBEROFTESTS]`, but for that I'd post another question.

Answer (score 0):

you are making few mistakes here you need to write your piece of code in some function say EEPROMDataTest() and call it from main routine or other thread context:

```
EEPROMDataTest()
{
Mytest1.Value = DATAEE_ReadByte(21); // Here i'm reading from epprom
Mytest2.Value = DATAEE_ReadByte(22); // Here i'm reading from epprom

// i need each eeprom values(from volatile variables) to get them inside an array

int  CheckMyValue[] = {Mytest1.Value, Mytest2.Value ... }
 //process further.
}
```

i assume you are reading from EEPROM .so,DATAEE_ReadByte is not a macro.